# Angular-ui typeahead with bootstrap3

Tags: javascript, django, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs

I am planning to move my project from `bootstrap-2` to `bootstrap-3`.

I use `angular-strap` as well.

Has anyone been able to successfully use angular-strap's `typeahead` with `bootstrap 3` ?

Honestly that is the only thing I use from `angular-strap`.

If not, are there any alternatives ?

Is it somehow possible to use `typeahead.js` by twitter ? 
I am using a `django` backend and I return json like this :
    views.py:

```
test = MyModel.objects.all()
return HttpResponse(serializers.serialize('json', test))
```

On my front end I use `select` but I want to be able to have a text box with `typeahead`

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used *angular-strap*, I use **Angular-UI Bootstrap** instead, since it's more actively developed.

We return JSON as well, our backend is using NodeJS though.

I just tried it out, using Bootstrap 3, AngularJS 1.2.3, Angular-UI - Bootstrap3 branch

things work fine, here is one of the snapshots (I am developing a mobile site :)

[image]